# Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token and Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: java

I have got two error message 1. Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token and 2. Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody. What is wrong with this code ?

```
public class AAExample
{
    int array[] = new int[3];
    array[0]= 10;
    array[1]=20;
    array[2]=30;
}
```

Comment: Place your code inside a method.

Comment: @rgettman Or initialization block.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot write free text comments without using either `//` or `/* ... */` as code comments.

Second, you can't initialize a variable like this, you can either do it inside initialize block:

```
public class AAExample
{
    int array[] = new int[3];
    {
        array[0] = 10;
        //enter code here
        array[1] = 20;
        array[2] = 30;
    }
}
```

or simply do it inside a constructor (or any other method):

```
public class AAExample
{
    int array[] = new int[3];

    AAExample() {
        array[0] = 10;
        //enter code here
        array[1] = 20;
        array[2] = 30;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put code outside of a method, so the following statements are wrongly placed.

`array[0]= 10; array[1]=20; array[2]=30;`

These assignments can be placed, for example, is the constructor of the class (or in other methods) :

```
public class AAExample
{
    int array[] = new int[3];
    public AAExample ()
    {
        array[0]=10;
        array[1]=20;
        array[2]=30;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all code must be written within a method (with the exception of one-line member initialization).